# Interfacing NAND flash with PCI

Tags: flash, interface

This is mostly an educational endeavor. I'm looking into prototyping a NAND flash storage on an embedded platform running Linux. The ONFi standard seems convenient and promising, but I'm failing to see how this standard interfaces with a standard PC hardware bus. Ideally, I would like to interface such a storage device with the PCI bus (vs an IDE, SATA, or USB interface). Can anyone provide some clarity or a resource with some additional information?

References:

- http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/nand-data/nanddata.html
- http://www.onfi.org/